# Sorting a list with next and prev values

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have objects that have the values  `id, next, prev`. Where `next` and `prev` have an value of an other `id`. These objects are in an rather arbitrary order. I want to get them in the order that the object, that has no previous object in the list comes at position one, then the object that has the id of the first objects next value and so on.

- The sort function should return a list of lists
- If there are distinct parts in the lists that can't be connected, those would be in two seperate lists. (So to speak: We have 2 endings and 2 beginnings)
- 0 denotes no prev/next
- The sort function should be as efficient as possible in terms of complexity
- pseudo code would be fine, no Javascript required

```js
let list = [
{"id": 181, "next": 182, "prev": 231},
{"id": 182, "next": 253, "prev": 181},
{"id": 230, "next": 231, "prev": 0},
{"id": 231, "next": 181, "prev": 230},
{"id": 253, "next": 254, "prev": 182},
{"id": 254, "next": 0, "prev": 253},
]

console.log("unordered", list.map(x => x.id))
let falsesorted = sortByNextPrev(list);
falsesorted.forEach(sub => {
  console.log(sub.map(x => x.id));
});

function sortByNextPrev(list){
 var sorted = list.reduce((acc,l) => {
     let last = acc[acc.length-1];
    if(last.length === 0 || last[last.length-1].next === l.id){
        last.push(l)
    }
    else if(last[0].prev === l.id){
        last.unshift(l);
    }
    else{
        acc.push([l]);
    }
    return acc;
},[[]]);
return sorted;
}
```

My function obviously does not achieve what I want. 
The order I try to achieve is `230,231,181,182,253,254`.

I tried to wrap my head around it, but I haven't found an efficient solution. I guess I could build a really stupid function, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a lookup function and start with the first element, putting them in the result array one after the other. The lookup could be done stupid simple with a loop, with a binary search in your sorted array, or optimised with a lookup table.

Let's choose the last approach, we need one iteration to find the first element anyway:

```
const byId = new Map();
const firsts = [];
for (const el of list) {
    byId.set(el.id, el);
    if (!el.prev) firsts.push(el);
}
const results = firsts.map(first => {
    const result = [];
    for (let x = first; x != null; x = byId.get(x.next))
        result.push(x);
    return result;
});
```

Comment: I tested it, it works for the case that we only have one "chain" in the list. It doesn't if we have more than one seqeuence.

Comment: @Strernd Ah, I didn't notice that based on your example, but it's relatively trivial to account for that as well

Answer (score 0):

The system is closed when none of the elements' prev or next attributes set to null.
If you know the system is closed you start with any element otherwhise you look for elements when prev element is null and next element is set. Then read this next element and look for it in the input array. Move it (delete from the input array) from input array to the end of output array. Then repeat the process until the input array is empty. I look for next element by looping over input array.

I have this kind of elements in structure (allConnectedParts are allparts available in the system).

```
allConnectedParts[id]={"id":id, "prev_id":connector.prev_id,"next_id":connector.next_id};
```

I did the similar sorting in simple way:

```
  let allOrderedParts=[] //output array with several sets of elements
  let orderedParts=[]; //output array with ordered elements for one set of elements
  let part = null;
  if (allConnectedParts) {
      for (;;) {
      if (isClosedSystem) {  //when all parts are connected togeteher
        part = Object.values(allConnectedParts).find(obj => obj.prev_id!==null && obj.next_id!==null);
      } else {
        part = Object.values(allConnectedParts).find(obj => obj.prev_id===null && obj.next_id!==null);
      }
      orderedParts.push(part);
      delete allConnectedParts[part.id];
          while(typeof part!="undefined" && part.next_id!==null) {
              part = allConnectedParts[part.next_id];
              if (typeof part=="undefined" && Object.keys(allConnectedParts).length==0) break;
              orderedParts.push(part); 
              delete allConnectedParts[part.id];
          }

        allOrderedParts.push(orderedParts);
        orderedParts=[];

        if (Object.keys(allConnectedParts).length==0) break; 
      }
  }
```